# Get the number of results of a given query through the cursor without using count() function in MongoDB

Tags: c++, mongodb

Mongo C++ driver provides a function to get a cursor with the results of a given query, e.g to get all the documents with the field `x` set to 1 in the `mycol` collection of the `mydb` database we can use the following (assume that `c` is a pointer to a `DBClientBase` object correctly configured):

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c->query("mydb.mycol", BSON(x << 1));
```

In addition, there is a function to get the number of results of a given query:

```
int n = c->count("mydb.mycol", BSON(x << 1));
```

I would need to know the number of results before starting to process the results of the query. The way that I know to do that is combine both operations in the following way:

```
int n = c->count("mydb.mycol", BSON(x << 1));
// Do some checking based on n
...
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c->query("mydb.mycol", BSON(x << 1));
// Process cursor results
...
```

However, that involves 2 operations at MongoDB level. Would it be possible to know the number of results a cursor provides before going through their results so I can save invoking `count()` function? Something like this:

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c->query("mydb.mycol", BSON(x << 1));
int n = (get the number from the 'cursor' variable in some way)
// Do some checking based on n
...
// Process cursor results
...
```

Comment: Are you sure that count() really does something over the wire? Or why do you want to avoid having two operations? I am using MongoDB in C# I do know not much about the C++ implementation. I am just curious.

Comment: I think so... as if you only run count() you get a valid result, so necessarily an interaction on the wire is needed from my program binary to the MongoDB server.

Comment: I think a query will return a cursor and the cursor should have a count function. That is how it is in the C# driver. A complete different approach would be to get one item after the other, allocate the memory for it dynamically and then count in the end. I would say it depends on your use case for the count. Probably you can do it without a count?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be late to the party, but cursor.size() appears to do exactly what you are asking for.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.size/#cursor.size